# Apply modifier to multiple objects?

Tags: modifiers, vertices, nurbs-surface

I'm using Blender 2.70. How do I apply the same modifier to multiple objects? None of the answers I searched for work, listed below:

- Apply modifier to one object, then select all, make applied object active, ctrl+c -> modifiers. The only choice I get from ctrl+c is "copy selection to buffer"
- Same as above, except alt+c -> mesh from curves/meta/surface/text. Nothing happens

Also, is there a better way to reduce polygon count on simple objects (rings, cylinders, etc) than decimate? That's what I'm using right now, but can't figure out how to apply it to all the objects in the scene.

Comment: Alt C works fine for me..

Comment: @Heartcloud May you please ask your second question separately?

Comment: As @gandalf3 points out, Alt C works for him. It also works for me. There's obviously something else that's wrong. If you include a screenshot or two and ideally upload your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend and edit the question to include the link to it, you stand a much better chance of having your question reopened than by getting angry.

Comment: I did read the question. They work just fine for me. For us to help you, could you explain *exactly* what you did and what happened? "Didn't work" doesn't really help. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks to me as if the OP is using the word "Apply" in a different context than people experienced with Blender would normally use it.  An example: the painter applied a coat of paint to a car.  In this context, "apply" means "add".  In the context of Blender, apply means to make the changes permanent.  If this is the case, then Ctrl+l will be the appropriate menu to use.